# benchmark my own servers

Tags: ubuntu, dell, benchmark

I have a pile of old and assorted servers. I want to benchmark,  stress test and collect all hardware info from them before putting them into test lab environment. I would also like to be able to compare results between these servers. What tools could I put on a live Linux USB to perform the above task?

I have used [hardinfo](https://github.com/lpereira/hardinfo) but it doesn't have the ability to compare stats with my own machines.

Regards

Comment: Run Folding@Home on them and see how many points each one gets? Or choose the highest PPD

Answer (score 1):

There's lies, damned lies and then there's benchmarks.

A systems performance is dependant on the pattern of the workload, and how this relates to CPU clock speed, L1/L2 cache size, L2 cache sharing, hyper threading, CPU type, bus speed, memory architecture, memory speed, disk interface, disk rotational speed, disk seek speed, disk buffer size, filesystem, FS abstraction (LVM, md etc)....

Benchmarks really have limited value. If you want to measure what performance you are likely to get running your application on the hardwar then run *your application* on the hardware. Otherwise just go with the numbers on the labels / published specs.